# SELECT NOT IN not fetching the rows

Tags: foreign-keys, mariadb, where-clause

When I run this query:

```
select * from log_connections where acc_id = 13526 and action not in(0,1)
```

I get 0 rows. But this query correctly returns the 2 matching rows:

```
select * from log_connections where acc_id = 13526 and action = 5
```

The weirder part is changing the `acc_id` to another value still works fine. All the columns in the table are NOT NULL.

It seems any time there's a combination of not 0 and 1 specifically then it comes up with nothing.

`not in (0,3,4)` = works
`not in (0,3,1)` = no results
`not in (1,3)` = works
`not in (1,0)` = no results

**Edit 1:**
I've narrowed down the problem further, and it seems to be something with foreign keys (which I'm not really an expert on). This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `_with_fk` (
`acc_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`action` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
INDEX `FK__with_fk_accounts` (`acc_id`),
INDEX `FK__with_fk_cfg_conn_types` (`action`),
CONSTRAINT `FK__with_fk_accounts` FOREIGN KEY (`acc_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK__with_fk_cfg_conn_types` FOREIGN KEY (`action`) REFERENCES `cfg_conn_types` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When I export and re-import the table, it works for a few seconds, but after a few seconds it stops working... I redid this with an `EXPLAIN` and it actually changes when it stops working. The `EXPLAIN` that works:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwMym.png

The `EXPLAIN` that doesn't:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgrGJ.png

Here's the smallest data I could get it to reproducing with: https://pastebin.com/nArwrg1k

Comment: Is `action` an enum?

Comment: No. This is table: https://i.imgur.com/gbGg0Qc.png

Comment: If I remove the `acc_id = 13526` it actually _shows up_ on the results...

Comment: It seems any time there's a combination of not 0 and 1 specifically then it comes up with nothing. `not in (0,3,4)` = works, `not in (0,3,1)` = no results, `not in (1,3)` = works, `not in (1,0)` = no results

Comment: Just wild guess, 'action' might be standard key word, try to user alia or rename column.

Comment: @Cleroth can you provide some more info? Can you add the result of `show create table log_connections` as well as the insert statement of the row you are fetching?

Comment: 1. use `[action]` instead of `action`  just in case it's a reserved word. 2. What data type is the action column?

Comment: Please provide enough data (acc_id, action) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid mariadb escapes with backticks not brackets

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=b1f7da4bd4532499a85ecc5fad2dd75e).

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati Wrapping it in backticks makes no difference.

Comment: @chiliNUT I've updated the question with more data. Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=9b5dbb546d17a4fc5020f297b65719df).

Comment: OK it seems it's the a bug... I was using 10.4.6 and it just got fixed in 10.4.7. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19820

Comment: Please put all [mre] code/data & other text relevant to your question in post as text.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in MariaDB 10.4/10.4.6: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19820
It's been fixed in 10.4.7